# При рекурсивном вычислении сумы 1-го(0-го) столбца матрицы выдает ошибку,самостоятельно разобраться у меня не получилось, подробности ниже

Tags: python-3.x, рекурсия

Проблема состоит в том что, когда а == 0  и мы заходим в условие выхода и должны вернуть возвращаем к(суму) то программа почему-то продолжает работать и несмотря на то что мы вроде-бы должны были выйти из рекурсии и вернуть к(суму) мы идём на следующую итерацию k +=s(n,n1,a-1,0,k) и после этой итерации выдает такую ошибку:unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
насколько я понимаю у меня функция здесь нулевая 
Также если n==2(размерность матрицы равно 2,то мне просто возвращает "None", хотя когда, я шёл дебагером то, к(сума) имела определенное значение
Скажите почему выдает такую ошибку, и как исправить(по-возможности)
Спасибо

```
import random
n1 = int(input('matrix(1): '))
n=[[random.randint(-20,40) for r in range(n1)] for s in range(n1)]# cоздаем матрицу
def s(n,n1,a,b=0,k=0):#передаем в функцию(матрица, размерность матрицы,индексы элементов, суму)
    k+=n[a][b]#считаем суму последнего элемента
    if a == 0:#условия выхода из рекусии
        return  k
    k +=s(n,n1,a-1,0,k)#сама рекурсия
print(s(n,n1,(n1-1)))#начальные агрументы функции(матрица,размерность,значение первого индекса
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, условие выхода из рекурсии необходимо проверять сразу.
Во-вторых, если `a != 0` то Ваша функция возвращает `None` (т.к. нет явного `return`). Отсюда на самой первой же итерации (если `a >= 2`) мы получаем:

```py
k += n[a][b]
k += None # Т.к. s(n,n1,a-1,0,k) ничего явно не возвращает, т.е. возвращает None
```

---

Как исправить:
Прогоните Ваш алгоритм на бумаге, ибо то что у Вас написано - полная чушь.

Comment: Вы говорите что при первой итерации у меня будет :"k += None" но тогда почему если идти по программе дебагером, то "к" принимает на каждом проходе функции значение, к тому же сумирует правильно ?, может я чего-то не понял ?

Comment: @OleksiyKoval Вызываем `s(n, n1, 2)`. `k += n[a][b]` - ок. `a != 0` - в `if` не заходим. `k += s(n,n1,1,0,k)` - сначала происходит вызов `s(n,n1,1,0,k)`. Попали в `s(n,n1,1,0,k)`. `k += n[a][b]` - ок. `a != 0` - в `if` не заходим. Вызываем `s(n,n1,1,0,k)`. Попадаем в `s(n,n1,0,0,k)`. `k += n[a][b]` - ок. `a == 0` - возвращаем (из `s(n,n1,0,0,k)`) `k` (обозначу за `new_k`). Этот `k` возвращается в `k += s(n,n1,1,0,k)`, т.е. `k += new_k`. Далее НИЧЕГО (None) не возвращается из `s(n,n1,1,0,k)` в `s(n, n1, 2)`, т.е. в `s(n, n1, 2)`: `k += None`. Вот и получили ошибку.

Comment: Только Вы должны были это проделать сами. Например на бумаге, как я Вам указал.

Comment: проблема в том что когда я шёл дебагером по программе я заходил в if и в return тоже, но потом опять попадал на рекурсию, хотя я читал что после return функция не может продолжаться , поэтому я и не понимаю